# Calling startAsync() on a servlet request throws IllegalStateException in a filter chain terminated by Jetty 9's ProxyServlet

Tags: java, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0, jetty-9

**Environment:**

- In my environment, Kibana 4.5.2 is running behind a "reverse proxy servlet" which is created by extending Jetty's "ProxyServlet" class.
- This is done so that the Kibana web interface can be accessed using the URL https://Jetty_Server_IP:8443/visual-analytics/proxy/... Requests for this URL are intercepted by the reverse proxy running in the Jetty Server and redirected to https://localhost:5601/... i.e., to the Kibana Server that is running in the same machine as the Jetty Server.
- The Kibana Server then processes the request forwarded by the Jetty Server and returns the response back to the web browser.
- **NOTE:** Jetty is running in "embedded mode" within my application.

**Issue:**

The "reverse proxy servlet" is mapped to the URL "/visual-analytics/proxy/*".

There is another "filter" that is mapped to the URL "/visual-analytics/proxy/elasticsearch/.kibana/search/*" in which a ContinuationListener is being used as indicated by the following code snippet:

```
    ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(myRequestWrapper).addContinuationListener(new ContinuationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeout(Continuation continuation) {
                            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Request timeout...");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Continuation continuation) {

                            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)continuation.getServletResponse();
                            if (httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK || httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED ) {
                                   //some business logic
                            }

                        }
                    });

    chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response);
```

The above ContinuationListener was working fine with **Jetty version 8.1.15.v20140411** and the listener's onComplete() method was being called. But after upgrading the Jetty version to **9.3.14.v20161028**, the ContinuationListener is no longer working i.e., neither the listener's onComplete() method nor the onTimeout() method is being called.

Since the ContinuationListener is no longer working, I replaced it with a "javax.servlet.AsyncListener" implementation as indicated by the following code snippet:

```
                AsyncContext asyncContext = myRequestWrapper.startAsync();
                asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                    {
                                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Async timeout...");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                    {
                                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Async start...");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                    {
                                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Async error...");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                    {
                          HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) event.getSuppliedResponse();
                         //HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) event.getAsyncContext().getResponse();
                        if (httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK || httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED ) {
                                    //some business logic
                        }
                    }
        }, myRequestWrapper, httpServletResponse);

        chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response);
```

But adding the above "AsyncListener" implementation resulted in the following "IllegalStateException":

> ```
>    https://164.99.175.139:8443/visual-analytics/proxy/elasticsearch/.kibana/search/test1?op_type=create
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=STARTED
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.startAsync(HttpChannelState.java:264)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.startAsync(Request.java:2235)
>             at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:432)
>             at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:432)
>             at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:432)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:88)
>             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1712)
>             at com.netiq.sentinel.kibana.search.KibanaSearchFilter.doFilter(KibanaSearchFilter.java:249)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
>             at com.netiq.sentinel.kibana.proxy.AcceptEncodingHeaderModificationFilter.doFilter(AcceptEncodingHeaderModificationFilter.java:37)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
>             at com.netiq.sentinel.kibana.proxy.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:41)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
>             at com.netiq.sentinel.kibana.proxy.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:104)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Line number 88 in "ProxyServlet.java" which is mentioned in the above stack trace has the following code:

```
final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
```

Is the "IllegalStateException" being thrown because the startAsync() method is being called twice on the same request - for the first time in my filter and for the second time in Jetty ProxyServlet's service() method? If yes, is there no way to use an "AsyncListener" in a filter chain that is terminated by Jetty's ProxyServlet?

Any pointers on how to proceed further would be greatly appreciated. Looking forward for any response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I fixed this issue as follows:

1. Instead of using Jetty's "ContinuationListener", I used Servlet 3.0's "AsyncListener", since Jetty's "ContinuationListener" does not seem to work after upgrading to **Jetty 9.3.14.v20161028**. This may be a Jetty bug.
2. The listener related code segment was located BEFORE the filter’s “chain.doFilter()” call. I moved this code segment to a position AFTER the filter’s "chain.doFilter()" call, so that I can retrieve the AsyncContext that is "already created" in the Jetty ProxyServlet's service() method. I can then add an AsyncListener to the retrieved AsyncContext.
3. I changed the “request.startAsync()” call in my filter to “request.getAsyncContext()” so that I am not starting a new AsyncContext which leads to the IllegalStateException, but only retrieving the AsyncContext that is already created in Jetty’s ProxyServlet.

So the updated code segment looks like this:

```
            chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response);

            AsyncContext asyncContext = myRequestWrapper.getAsyncContext();
            asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                {
                            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Async timeout...");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                {
                            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Async start...");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                {
                            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Async error...");
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException 
                {
                      HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) event.getSuppliedResponse();
                     //HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) event.getAsyncContext().getResponse();
                    if (httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK || httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED ) {
                                //some business logic
                    }
                }
    }, myRequestWrapper, httpServletResponse);
```